# jQuery to bind click behavior to a collection of matching elements

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add a jQuery handler for each of my checkbox inputs so that when their value is changed (via a click directly on them or via a click on the labels bound to them via the "for" attribute), to true (or checked="checked") a class called "selected" is added to the parent li element.

Conversely, when the checkbox is unchecked by a click event, I want to remove the "selected" class from the li element.

```
<li class="section">
    <label class="left" for="my_ad_stacked">Left Label</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_ad_stacked" id="my_ad_stacked" value="true"  />
    <label for="my_ad_stacked" class="description check ">label info goes here</label>
</li>
```

I know that If I know the id or class of an element, I can use $('myElement').addClass('selected') and $('myElement').removeClass('selected'). I'm just not certain how to attach the behavior, dynamically to all checkbox elements, and their "for" bound labels.

Comment: I suggest to put the checkbox inside the label: `<label for="my_ad_stacked"><span class="left"> Left Label</span> <input type="checkbox" name="my_ad_stacked" id="my_ad_stacked" value="true" /> <span class="description check ">label info goes here</span></label>` Then all you have to do is to listen to the `change` event on the checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
   $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

This binds a `change` event to every `input` element of type `checkbox`. When one changes, the event handler function runs, and toggles the `selected` class on the closest `li` element.

In the event handler, `this` refers to the checkbox that has changed, so this will work for all checkboxes (assuming all checkboxes on your page have an `li` element ancestor).

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdmpB/2/) showing this in action.

Comment: toggleClass is not reliable in this case, you need to explicitly check if the checkbox is checked or not, because not every click toggles checkbox.checked. (see my solution below)

Comment: @valipour - I'm binding the `change` event, not the `click` event, so it should work fine. See the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: what if the checkbox was initially checked?

Comment: It will still work, the `toggleClass` will just be toggling the opposite way around. If some checkboxes are checked by default on load, then you could check for that in a `$(document).ready` function and apply the correct style then.

Comment: @valipour: `toggleClass` takes a second argument which indicates whether to add or remove the class. `.toggleClass("selected", this.checked)` should be fine.

Comment: I'm already using php to set the selected class onto each li item that's selected when the page loads, so no issues with preselected checkboxes in that regard.

Comment: cool, something told from inside that .toggleClass("selected", this.checked) exist, thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox, :checkbox + label").click(function()
{
    var li = $(this).closest("li");
    var chk = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox");

    if(chk.is(":checked")) li.addClass("selected");
    else li.removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this),
        $li = $checkbox.parents('li');
    if($checkbox.is(':checked')){
        $li.addClass('selected');
    } else{
        $li.removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

[Test it here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/S5KWC/)